# How to copy local changes from one pc to another using git

Tags: git

I'm using Git and sometimes i start my work on my local desktop and i want to copy these open works to my laptop to finish it at home.

To keep my repository clean, i don't want to push these changes to some branch because my work may be unfinished, untested an so on...

Comment: You can commit and undo the commit later, keeping your repository "clean". I don't think that pushing unfinished work is a bad practice, you can do it as an initial commit, nothing wrong with that IMO.

Comment: What's the problem in your approach?

Comment: If more than one user is working on the same branch, i think it's better to avoid pushing unfinished work.  Yes it's possible to commit and undo but i think it's more complicated.

Comment: @Gatschet then create your own branch, what's the problem with that?

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan: Nothing. This should just help other people with same problem.

Comment: Why don't you create a sub branch to commit your work and pull it at home? it wont affect "master" and nevermind the work is not finish, it's the concept

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I think its too complicated to just make a branch (and delete them after) to copy some open work to another PC

Comment: @Gatschet, **Then post this as answer to the question**. Otherwise, people will be confused. We use the same way with both git and svn, but the commands are different for git and svn :)

Comment: I agree. I changed my question and answered it...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is my workflow to copy my changes from one PC to another:

Stash your changes with:

```
git stash save myWork
```

Save stash to file with:

```
git stash show -p  > myWork.txt
```

Move (using email etc) generated file (myWork.txt) to other PC. Patch new PC with:

```
git apply myWork.txt
```

Clear all Stash on original PC:

```
git stash clear
```

Comment: It would be very wise to include the `--include-untracked` option when stashing, so that it includes any files you have created but not yet added.

Comment: When you use git stash, it reverts the changes locally, which may not be what you want. If you want to export the current changes, just use `git diff > myWork.txt`. The result can be applied in the same way as the stash.

Answer (score 6):

You're over-complicating the problem, all what you need to do is:

At work

```
git checkout -b temp_branch
git push origin temp_branch
```

At home

```
git fetch && git checkout temp_branch
```

Then delete it:

```
git branch -d temp_branch
git push origin :temp_branch
```

For extra cleaning, you can prune the deleted branch

```
git remote prune temp_branch
```

Don't be afraid of creating branches, they're very cheap.

Comment: As you see in "Delete a Git branch both locally and remotely" it's not so easy to delete a branch...

Comment: It's actually very easy.. `git branch -d temp_branch` will delete it locally, `git push origin :temp_branch` will delete it in the remote.

Comment: This breaks history - you are forced to create a commit and the local source tree might not be in a sufficiently good state to create a meaningful atomic commit with a good message.  This commit will make it to everybody's history eventually. If the message is bad, you will have to either work with it further through squashing, or tinkering with history.  I like the idea of @Gatschet with stashing to a file much more useful for this use case. This helps to move to another machine when you need, not when you can make a relatively clean commit.

Comment: @Maroun This also doesn't work if there are pre-commit hooks, CI builds, tests etc. that could cause failures and warning messages.

Answer (score 0):

Create a feature branch and push it to remote repo. You can sync your work via feature branches easily. Then you can merge it to main branch.

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to push commits up to save even unfinished work. Sometimes you can lose valuable man hours if something bad happens.
My preferred method is to use either a private commit or a wip(work in progress) commit:

```
git push HEAD:refs/for/master%private
git push HEAD:refs/for/master%wip
```

More details are here:

```
https://gerritcodereview-test.gsrc.io/marking-a-change-as-private.html
https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-upload.html
```

Then you can checkout the branch from another computer any time and your changes are also saved to remote without anyone being able to see it until you are ready.